# Which company in England is most reliable for storing boxes?

Tags: uk

I travel to England often, and must store 5 large boxes of personal property (no priceless treasures) for around 6 months, currently situated in Coventry. I  will ask the company to deliver the boxes to London, my next frequented destination. Each box is smaller than the size of a typical checked bag for air travel (90cm x 75cm x 43cm).

A Google search returns many websites, but being away from England, I have no method to check which is cheapest and safest.

Comment: I used one on the North Circular Road and another one on the A13 towards Thurrock.  No problems encountered. Price-wise: I recommend something outside the North Circular, but inside the Orbital.  Both of mine were inside or adjacent to a trading estate.  Are you looking for the contact details of a specific company?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big Yellow Self Storage is a large storage company that has many locations around the UK. the nearest to coventry is in [Birmingham](http://www.bigyellow.co.uk/storesearch/searchresults?location=Coventry). I've used them twice in London and my friends have as well (I used to study there) and they've been very helpful. Some locations offer extended access hours 06:00 - 23:00 and they should be happy to help you move stuff as well. I'd just give them a call and tell them about your predicament.

This is the only company I have used but as far as I know there are many many more. I think any large company will be very similar in service and I'd just give it a quick Google if you don't want to go with Big Yellow. Unfortunately that's the only one I've used so can't really report about any others.

Comment: My experience with Big Yellow has been good too, but they don't do collection/delivery.

Comment: They themselves don't do it but it says on their site that they can [help to move it](http://www.bigyellow.co.uk/removals).

Comment: Purely personal anecdote but I used Aussie Man & Van to store the contents of my flat for a few months (they collect and deliver too) and was happy with the service.